# Open Set in Composition of Mappings

Tags: general-topology

Let X, Y, and Z be topological spaces, and let f: X —> Y and g: Y —> Z, and let U, V, be open sets of Y and Z respectively.

Given arbitrary set A in X, if g(f(A)) is open in Z, does that imply A is open in X?  I am interested in knowing when the inverse image of a set can be open when we consider composition of continous maps and their open set images.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with compositions. You might as well just ask if whether $f(A)$ open in $Y$ implies $A$ open in $X$ for a mapping $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$. The answer is no and counter-examples abound. For example take $X$ to be any topological space, $A$ any non-open subset of $X$, $Y$ a singleton with its only topology and $f$ to be the constant map.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if $g \circ f$ is a quotient map. And this happens if $g$ and $f$ are quotient maps. But otherwise there can be loads of counterexamples. You need assumptions on $f$ and $g$ or there is no hope of this holding.